# Vue 3 Composition api pass data boject to child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to pass reactive data object to child, but app shows blank page without error message whatsoever. I want to use composition api.

Parent:

```
<template>
  <Landscape :viewData="viewData"/>
</template>

<script>
  import { onMounted, onUnmounted, ref, inject } from 'vue';

  export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const resizeView = ref(false)
    const mobileView = ref(false)
    const viewData = reactive({resizeView, mobileView})
    viewData.resizeView.value = false
    viewData.mobileView.value = false
    // lets do sth to change viewData

    return {
      viewData
    }
  },
  components: {
      Landscape
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>resize- {{viewData.resizeView}} mob {{viewData.mobileView}}
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Header',
  props: {
    viewData: Object,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

everything works, when in parent, data object is passed directy like this

```
<Landscape :viewData="{resizeView: false, mobileView: false}"/>
```

Comment: `const viewData = reactive({resizeView: false, mobileView: true})` you can remove two refs and use a single reactive variable. there are other options too.

Comment: and directly change `viewData.resizeView = true;`, it is reactive.

Comment: It's not a good practice to pass writable object that could be modified as a prop. `viewData.resizeView.value` - it's not a ref, refs are unwrapped inside reactive object, otherwise it wouldn't make much sense to keep it `reactive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Vue docs about `reactive` objects:

> The reactive conversion is "deep"—it affects all nested properties.

So you don't need to wrap every variable as a `ref` in `reactive` object (unless you want to unwrap ref variable). Check [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) for more info about reactivity API in Vue.

I provided some basic usage of `ref` and `reactive` with your `Landscape` component. Paste this in your `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <button @Click="changeResize" type="button">Change ref values</button>
  <Landscape :viewData="viewData" />

  <br />
  <br />

  <button @Click="changeReactiveSize" type="button">
    Change reactive values
  </button>
  <Landscape :viewData="otherViewData" />
</template>

<script>
  import { onMounted, onUnmounted, ref, inject } from 'vue';

  export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const resizeView = ref(false);
    const mobileView = ref(false);
    const viewData = {
      resizeView,
      mobileView,
    };
    const changeResize = () => {
      viewData.resizeView.value = !viewData.resizeView.value;
      viewData.mobileView.value = !viewData.mobileView.value;
    };

    const otherViewData = reactive({
      mobileView: false,
      resizeView: false,
    });

    const changeReactiveSize = () => {
      otherViewData.resizeView = !otherViewData.resizeView;
      otherViewData.mobileView = !otherViewData.mobileView;
    };

    return {
      viewData,
      otherViewData,
      changeResize,
      changeReactiveSize,
    };
  },
  components: {
      Landscape
    }
  }
```

You can also check this code example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fxya5n?file=src/App.vue).